# If $QMQ^{-1}$ is diagonal will $Q^{-1}MQ$ be diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a matrix and let $Q$ be a matrix such that $QMQ^{-1}$ is diagonal. My question is probably obvious, but will $Q^{-1}MQ$ be diagonal? First I had in mind that perhaps $QMQ^{-1}=Q^{-1}MQ$ but this looks obviously wrong. And really, I don't know how to proceed... but maybe it's wrong?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Why would $M$ be necessarily invertible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: if we set
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
and
$$ Q = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \implies Q^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} , $$
then
$$ QMQ^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} a & -a+b \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
but
$$ Q^{-1}MQ = \begin{pmatrix} a & a+b \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} , $$
and clearly we can choose $a,b$ so that one of these is diagonal and one not.

Answer (score 1):

No. A reason is if it would be the case, then column of $Q^{-1}$ and column of $Q$ would contain eigenvectors of $M$. Since normally the column of $Q$ and the column of $Q^{-1}$ are different, we would have more eigenvectors than the dimension of the space, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently:

> For all diagonal matrices $D$ and for all invertible matrices $Q$, the matrix $Q^{-2}DQ^2$ is diagonal.

And that just isn't a thing: consider, for instance, that $Q^2$ may the generic symmetric positive definite matrix.